# Offload App option in iOS11 beta is not present

Tags: ios11

I tried building my app through xcode 9 and installed on iOS11 beta 6 phone. But I could not see "offload app" option for my app (setting->iphone->storage->myapp).

I could see only "delete app" option. I tried app installed both through xcode and itunes (ipa).

But for other apple store , downloaded app I see both the option "offload app" and "delete app".

Any idea, why it is not appearing for my app, any setting required in app while building/packaging to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that its a App Store feature is and only available with app uploaded on app store.